# xpath attribute contain special character

Tags: python, xpath

```
<img width="410" height="410" #src="http://XXXX1.png" src="http://xxxx2.png" alt=""/>
```

I want to extract image address http://xxxx1.png ,
I'm using  /img/@#src but get nothing.it contain # char .

Any suggestions? 
thank you for help.

Comment: why is there a `#` there? I don't think that's valid HTML

Comment: @JamieRees: it isn't. Though browsers acting as they are, I wouldn't be surprised if it actually got parsed in a browser. But it is definitely not valid XML or HTML.

Comment: It's HTML ,  not xml format.

Comment: Doesn't matter as XPath can only be used to query XML documents, so you can't search for attributes with invalid XML attribute names because those are a syntax error in XPath expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <img width="410" height="410" #src="http://XXXX1.png" src="http://xxxx2.png" alt=""/>
> ```

Unfortunately, you cannot do this with XPath, as this fragment is invalid XML. [An XML NameChar cannot start, or contain, the hash symbol](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html). And XPath can only deal with an XML tree, and from this fragment, you cannot create such a tree (any XML parser will break on that fragment).

To fix this, pre-process your not-really-XML and make it correct, by removing that symbol. Or fix it at the source, if you have access to this, by not generating invalid names to begin with.

Note: there is no mechanism in XML (or HTML for that matter) to use some kind of escape sequence. Entity references may only be used in values and text nodes.

Comment: thank you ,  I   solved the problem by replace #src to other tag ,

Answer (score 0):

If it's not valid XML you can't use XPath to query that attribute as the name is invalid syntax in an XPath expression.

As it is not even a valid HTML attribute name you will need a lenient HTML parser which doesn't choke on that attribute *and* even preserves it in the results instead of ignoring invalid attribute names.  The combination BeautifulSoup with `html5lib` for parsing seems to work. The HTML parser in the Python standard library chokes on that attribute and `lxml.html` silently ignores it.

```
In [33]: import bs4

In [34]: source
Out[34]: '<img width="410" height="410" #src="http://XXXX1.png" src="http://xxxx2.png" alt=""/>'

In [35]: doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')

In [36]: doc.img.attrs
Out[36]: 
{u'#src': u'http://XXXX1.png',
 u'alt': '',
 u'height': u'410',
 u'src': u'http://xxxx2.png',
 u'width': u'410'}

In [37]: doc.img.attrs['#src']
Out[37]: u'http://XXXX1.png'
```